# MVC Problem trying to upload file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have googled this code to upload a file with MVC.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Task/SaveFile">
<input type="file" id="FileBlob" name="FileBlob"/>
<input type="submit"  value="Save"/>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='/'" />
</form>
```

But when interrogate the forms["FileBlob"] it is null when I browse a file and submit the form????

Malcolm

EDIT: I have added a textbox to the form and I can get that value fine. Just the input type file is not working?

```
bool errors = false;
   //this field is never empty, it contains the selected filename
   if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( forms["FileBlob"] ) )
   {
       errors = true;
       ModelState.AddModelError( "FileBlob", "Please upload a file" );
   }
   else
   {
      string sFileName = forms["FileBlob"];
      var file = Request.Files["FileBlob"];
      //'file' is always null, and Request.Files.Count is always 0 ???
      if ( file != null )
      {
         byte[] buf = new byte[file.ContentLength];
         file.InputStream.Read( buf, 0, file.ContentLength );
         //do stuff with the bytes
      }
      else
      {
         errors = true;
         ModelState.AddModelError( "FileBlob", "Please upload a file" );
      }
   }
   if ( errors )
   {
      return ShowTheFormAgainResult(); 
   }
   else
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Woah that is one confusing setup, I personally would never complicate things like that with all those if statements and for null values do via jquery validation you can also do server side validation. Instead of checking `if(errors)` do `if(ModelState.IsValid){ return View();}` here is a better interpretation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410404.aspx

this way you can get rid of that bool setup.

Also check here

http://blogs.msdn.com/stcheng/archive/2009/03/20/asp-net-how-to-implement-file-upload-and-download-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

for an easier implemenation of your upload structure. I've used it and didn't run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653469/1653508#1653508) might help. Also, i'd suggest not posting other form fields with the uploading file.. do that separately in a separate action. Sure this gives the user 2 steps, but believe me it's worth the simplicity on your end.